# How does z-index work for float?

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply a z-index to a floated image and why this does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index only applies to elements positioned not statically, aka give it a position of absolute, relative, fixed ( and maybe some other ).

Comment: Note that this is completely independent of `float`ing. So you can have a floated, relatively positioned element with a z-index.